# How to combine two Signals with OR

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I have two Signals from Notifications. These where fired from an external framework.

```
let successSignal = NotificationCenter.default.reactive.notifications(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "someNotification"))
let failedSignal = NotificationCenter.default.reactive.notifications(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "someNotification"))
```

Now I want to combine them to one signal of type `Signal<Notification, Error>`.
If `successSignal` fires send Value, if `failedSinal` fires send Error.

I have no idea how to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this:

```
enum SignalErrors: Error {
    case failedSignalValue
}

let failingFailed = failedSignal.flatMap(FlattenStrategy.latest) { _ in
    return SignalProducer<Int, SignalErrors>(error: SignalErrors.failedSignalValue)
}
```

For this new signal, a value on the `failedSignal` will be turned into an `error` Event, so `failingFailed` is a Signal on which events on `failedSignal` now arrive as `.failed` instead of `.value`.

Keep the [Event Stream Grammar](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Documentation/APIContracts.md#the-event-contract) in mind - after one `.failed` event, the Signal terminates!

```
let merged = Signal.merge([
    successSignal
        .promoteError(SignalErrors.self),
    failingFailed
])
```

Then we merge the `successSignal` and `failingFailed` signal together. [Since a `.failed` event behaves like an exception and propagates immediately](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Documentation/APIContracts.md#failures-behave-like-exceptions-and-propagate-immediately), the whole merged signal will also fail immediately when a `.failed` event arrives on `failingFailed`.

The `promoteError` on `successSignal` is necessary for type checking reasons.